# Function To Alter Text In All Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I am wanting to scan column X and any cell that has a text length of > 11 - I want to pop up a message box asking the user to alter it.  Once the user hits the okay button I then want to replace all of those values in column X.  This is the syntax that I have, but it is not iterating each cell.  Once I type in a new rename value the macro will continue to ask me, but it appears to not iterate the cells further down column X.

What must I change in order to have this macro function as I desire?

```
Function ShortenText()
Dim c As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim NewValue As String

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Range("X1:X" & lRow)
        Cells(c.Row, 2) = Len(c)
        If Len(c) > 11 Then
            NewValue = Trim(InputBox("What would you like to rename the value")
            Selection.Replace What:=c.Value, Replacement:=NewValue, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      End If
    Next c

End Function
```

Comment: You are performing a `Replace` on `Selection`, but your code never `Select`s any range.  Possibly changing `Selection.Replace` to `Range("X1:X" & lRow).Replace` may do what you want, if you want to change everything in column X that has the same value as in the cell being currently processed to the same new value specified by the user.  But if you want the user to change each cell to a different value (e.g. one occurrence of "longish string" to "x" and another occurrence of "longish string" to "y") then you probably only want to say `c.Value = NewValue` rather than doing a `Range.Replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code. Make only a little modification :

```
Function ShortenText()
Dim c As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim NewValue As String

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 24).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Range("X1:X" & lRow)
        Cells(c.Row, 2) = Len(c)
        If Len(c) > 11 Then
            NewValue = Trim(InputBox("What would you like to rename the value"))
            c.Select
            Selection.Replace What:=c.Value, Replacement:=NewValue, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      End If
    Next c

End Function
```

Add "c.Select" and close the Trim function ")".

Comment: If you are only doing the `Replace` on a single cell, you may as well just say `c.Value = NewValue`.  Then you don't need the `Select` or the `Replace`.